# Facing error while configuring for Apache JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder

Tags: java, apache, jmeter

While i am executing Basic Instructions to configure Apache JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder as mentioned at http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf .
I am facing error in one dialog box while clicking on start button of HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder. Error is as below,

```
Could not create script reording proxy - see log for details: Command :"keytool -getkeypair -alias :root_ca: -dname "CN=_DO NOT INSTALL unless this is your certificate (JMeter root CA), OU=Username:ketan.patel, C=US" -keyalg RSA -keystore proxyserver.jks -storepass{redacted)-keypass{redacted)-valididity 7 -ext bc:c' failed, code: 1
Illegal option: -ext
Try keytool -help
```

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Read this :

- https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/TestRecording210

If you are using JMeter 2.10, it's better to upgrade to 2.11

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem.So,i upgrade java 1.6 to 1.7 then the problem is resolved

or else

you can try this

set the java path in jmeter.bat file like

example

set JAVA_HOME=c:\programfiles\java\jdk1.7

set path=%path%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin